# Magento | Configurable Swatches Tab doesn't appear in The Admin page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, color-swatches

I am trying to add a product with color swatches. when I searched I found a lot of articles like this: 
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html

but I can't find Configurable swatches Tab in My admin below the catalog as it was explained in Magento official documentation!

Our Magento version: 1.9.0.1

Can you please help us in this point?

Thanks,